# xbox360 HDMI connection failure

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360

I'm currently having problems connecting my xbox360 to my TV using HDMI. When I connect my 360 with AV cables, I do have a picture, but using an HDMI cable doesn't work. I have tried different ports and changed cables but I always get the same results; it's not working.

Could someone help me figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to Arqade. Could you provide some pictures of what's going on to help us figure out the issue?

Comment: hate to be that guy, but are you sure your tv is on the right input?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking and cleaning the HDMI ports and the cord itself. if you have something else that runs on HDMI you can switch the cord between the two and check if that is the problem.